# polar coordinates vector equation of a rectangle

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates

We can write the equation of the circle in vector form in polar coordinates as:

$$\vec{r}=R\hat{r}$$ ; where 'R' is the radius of the circle.

Similarly, can we write the vector equation for a rectangle in polar coordinates? If so, how?

Answer (score 9):

Let $(\pm a,\pm b)$ be the vertices of the rectangle.

When $x=a$, $r\cos \theta=a$

When $y=b$, $r\sin \theta=b$

Hence, $$r(\theta)=
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \displaystyle \frac{a}{|\cos \theta \,|} & , &
    \displaystyle |\tan \theta \,| \leq \frac{b}{a} \\
    \displaystyle \frac{b}{|\sin \theta \,|} & , &
    \displaystyle |\tan \theta \,| \geq \frac{b}{a} \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$