# area of a rectangle

Tags: probability, integration, area

I know that to use polar coordinates instead of $dxdy$ we have $dA=rdrd\theta$. As such, we can have a double integral like
$$
\int_{\theta=a}^{\theta=b}\int_{r=c(\theta)}^{r=d(\theta)}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin(\theta))rdrd\theta. 
$$
In my case $f(x\cos\theta,y\sin(\theta))=p(r)$.
My problem happens when I have, for example, instead of a pdf $p(r)$, a cdf function $P_R(r)$. I am trying to evaluate an 'area' of a rectangle using this function. In this case, can I evaluate it using something like
$$
\int_{\theta=a}^{\theta=b}P_R(r_1(\theta))d\theta - \int_{\theta=a}^{\theta=b}P_R(r_2(\theta))d\theta
$$? And $r_1>r_2 \geq 0$. What about the term $r$?

thanks

Comment: I am sorry if this is wrong because I do not know much about statistics, but from my understanding, the cdf is the integral of the pdf, so if you use the cdf, that means you already took the integral with respect to $r$. Again, I could definitely be wrong here, but since no one else is posting here, this is my best guess as to why the double integral is now a single integral once you use a cdf.

Comment: I have no idea what a cdf or pdf is and maybe Noble is right that you've already taken the derivative wrt $r$.  But if not, then the line element is $ds = rd\theta$ when $r=$constant.  Or $ds = \sqrt{dr^2+r^2d\theta^2}$ if $r$ not constant.

Comment: What is the probability function over? If it is converting some point in the rectangle to a probability then the CDF should kinda solve your problem shouldn't it? I don't see why you would even need to integrate it since generally the cumulative distribution function has already integrated for you. If this is some hybrid probability and ??? then you should clarify the ??? part.

Comment: sorry, I will try to explain it better. By the definition of a cdf $P_R(r_1)=\int_0^{r_1}{p(r) dr}$. At first equation there, $\int_{\theta=a}^{\theta=b}\int_{r=c(\theta)}^{r=d(\theta)}p(r)rdrd\theta$, how I can replace it if there is a term $r$ there? Is anything wrong?

Comment: I expect you have a specific problem in mind. That would be easier to deal with than attempts at generality. By the way, it looks as if the first displayed formula should have $f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$.

Comment: See how to express a rectangle in polar coordinates in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703952/polar-coordinates-vector-equation-of-a-rectangle/1704732#1704732)

Comment: @AndréNicolas you are right