# Sine applied to a square

Tags: geometry, periodic-functions

I asked myself about what would happen if we applied the sine and cosine formulas to a square.

Because a picture is worth a thousand words :

[image: The picture]

Of course, when the $x$ line is facing down, $x$ is negative, and the same when the $y$ line is at the left of the graph.

It seems clear that :

$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

And that, when $\theta \in [0;2\pi]$ :

$$y = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \theta \in \left[0;\frac{\pi}{4}\right] \cup \left[\frac{7\pi}{4};2\pi\right] $$
$$x = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{4};\frac{3\pi}{4}\right]$$
$$y = -1 \Longleftrightarrow \theta \in \left[\frac{3\pi}{4};\frac{5\pi}{4}\right]$$
$$x = -1 \Longleftrightarrow \theta \in \left[\frac{5\pi}{4};\frac{7\pi}{4}\right]$$

Else, what would be the best way to calculate $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: For your interest, see [**another answer**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703952/polar-coordinates-vector-equation-of-a-rectangle/1704732#1704732)