# Find the area of a rectangle with the radius

Tags: calculus, geometry

A rectangle could be described by a function $\theta\rightarrow R(\theta)$ which gives the distance from the centre $C$ of the rectangle to the perimeter at the angle $\theta$:
[image]

Could this function $R$ be used to find the area of the rectangle?

Comment: Refer to another answer [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703952/polar-coordinates-vector-equation-of-a-rectangle/1704732#1704732)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the area is given by the integral:
$$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} R(\theta)^2 \; d\theta $$
(follows e.g. by looking at the area as a Riemann sum).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left[2R\cos\left(\theta\right)\right]\left[2R\sin\left(\theta\right)\right] =
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{2R^{2}\sin\left(2\theta\right)}
$$

Comment: It's admittedly difficult to be absolutely certain, but I think it was only an accident (or perhaps one should say an unfortunate choice of an example for the angle $\theta$) that caused the radius at angle $\theta$ to meet the rectangle at a vertex. The idea of "a function $\theta\to R(\theta)$" seems to imply that for a given rectangle, $\theta$ could be any angle.

Comment: @DavidK We need two parameters to evaluate the rectangle area: The sides length. I guess I misunderstood the original statement as 'Given $R$ and $\theta$'$\ldots$ I'll delete $\color{#f00}{or}$ modify my answer very soon. Thanks for your remark.